# Show that $f(n) = -\sqrt{n} + n\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right), f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a decreasing function.

Tags: calculus

The way I tried to approach this question was to consider it as a continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I then tried to show that $\frac{d}{dx}f < 0$. So

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x) &= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{x}} \left(x^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right) \\
&= \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2 + \sqrt{x}}{x + \sqrt{x}}\right).
\end{align*}
Using the substitution $x = \frac{1}{u^2}$ gives

$$\log(1+u) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u^2}{u+1} + u\right).$$
At this point I'm stuck. How do I show this thing is negative for $u>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the first derivative again, you made a mistake (last term of your first line).

You'll get a function $f'$ whose sign is not straightforward. Therefore, you'll need the second derivative $f''$, which on the other hand is easy to study.

You should find that $f''$ is always positive on your domain, hence $f'$ is always increasing. Now, I said that the sign of $f'$ is not straightforward, but you could easily compute its *limit* as $x\mapsto\infty$.

Now, what can you say about the overall sign of a function, given the limit you've just computed and the fact that it is strictly increasing?

Final step, use the (constant?) sign of $f'$ to deduce the behaviour of $f$. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error, I had entirely missed that. I now have the derivative as $\log(1 + 1/\sqrt{x}) - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x} + 1}{x + \sqrt{x}}\right)$ which has the properties you described.

Comment: @BallzofFury Looks right to me :)

Comment: After some tedious calculations, we indeed have that $f'$ is increasing and tends towards $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. So $f'$ must be negative and thus $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: @BallzofFury Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To complete what you had begun, compute the second derivative and study the function $f'$. Deduce its sign from its table of variations.